# Listing floats from array with format

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsnumberformatter

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains floats. I can display one float in a specific format or display all of them without formatting but I cannot figure out how to do both at once. I first wrap the float in an `NSNumber` so that it can be added to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.10f];
[array addObject:num];
```

`NSNumberFormatter` works for formatting the numbers to be displayed in a `textView`. Here is the code I used to do that:

```
 for (NSNumber *aNumber in array) {

self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" 
[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:aNumber 
numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]];

}
```

The obvious problem here is the text is replaced with the number in the array each time the loop runs rather than listing all of them.

So, I did more research and found `componentsJoinedByString`:

```
 self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

This worked well to list them but lacked the formatting style: It displays, for example, 5.10 as 5.1 which I don't want. I tried to combine them somehow but it didn't work, and I also tried `stringByAppendingString` in the loop using the formatter but that was a mess that did not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the text in the textView instead of appending..

```
 for (NSNumber *aNumber in array) {
    NSString *result = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:aNumber 
numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    if (aNumber == array.firstObject && !self.textView.text.length) {
        self.textView.text = result;
    }
    else {
        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.textView.text, result];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was trying to achieve. The only problem is it displays as `, $5.50, $23.13, $1.00` with that first leading comma. I can move the comma to the end but then the last number will have a comma when it doesn't need one: `...$1.00,`

Comment: @JohnL; Fixed. It should now handle the first one correctly. "$5.50, $23.13, $1.00"

Comment: At first it didn't change anything then I took out the second part of your `if` statement: `&& !self.textView.text.length`. Then it displayed perfectly. Let me know if that was actually some necessary piece, though. Either way, thanks!

Comment: It would be much simpler to fill a new array with the formatted strings (similar to the OP's original code) and then use `componentsJoinedByString` to build the final string.